# Change list of blogs based on category selection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completely drawing a blank on my problem here.

I have a list of blog posts that are being displayed by category:

```
const Posts = ({ state }) => {

  const data = state.source.get(state.router.link);
  const postsPerCategory = getPostsGroupedByCategory(state.source);
  console.log(postsPerCategory);

  return (
    <>
    {postsPerCategory.map(({ posts, category }, index) => {
        return (
          <button key={index}>
            {category.name}
          </button>
        )
      })}
      {postsPerCategory.map(({ posts, category }, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h1>{category.name}</h1>
            {posts.map((post, index) => {
              return (
                <article key={index}>
                  {console.log(post)}
                  {post.title.rendered}
                </article>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

I have a section above the list here that creates a button for each category. I am trying to have it display so that when a category button is clicked, only those posts are shown below. I know the mapping would have to be a bit different than what I have now, I am just drawing a blank on where to go from here.

The structure of `postsPerCategory` is:
[image]

Comment: Pls share structure of postpercategory..You will need to put filter on array to achieve this .

Comment: @sgrmhdk i updated with the structure

Comment: I was thinking it should be set up where I have another component <PostsInCategory category={.. whatever selected category ..}, it passes that category information with the posts in that category, so the PostsInCategory component would update to show the posts based on the category selected.

Comment: "I am trying to have it display so that when a category button is clicked" -> currently nothing (intentional) happens when the button is clicked. You're going to want to attach some kind of click handler to move forward.

Comment: @JakeWorth yes, I'm just a but lost on how to do that right now. I realize it's a basic thing, but I have been staring at this so long i am bit brain dead

Comment: @kb_ I hear you! This you need an onClick handler and you need state. This docs page has several relevant examples. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

If the data structure is like so:

```js
const postsPerCategory = [
  {
    posts: [],
    category: {id: 1, name: "cat 1"},
  }
]
```

Then in order to get posts by a given category, you can use filter

```js
const getPostsByCategory = (category_id) => {
  const found = postsPerCategory.filter(v => v.category.id == category_id);
  if (found.length > 0) {
    return found[0].posts;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Now call this function in the `onClick` of button

Notes: I think you should use `React.useMemo` to get categories to increase performance and don't always use index as key for components use something like `key={'category_'+c.id}`

```
const categories = React.useMemo(() => postsPerCategory.map(v => {id: v.category.id, name: v.category.name}), [postsPerCategory]);
```